# Fatal error: [snuffleupagus][disabled_function] Aborted execution on call of the function 'chmod' and 'include'

Tags: cakephp, php-7.4, php-7.3, cakephp-2.x

I have my application based on CakePHP 2.10.24.

When I used PHP 7.3 all works well but when I use PHP 7.4 several errors happend:

I should noticed that on WAMP all works fine but not on webserver on CPanel.

I add some codes to trace easier.

Thanks

```
Array
(
    [0] => /php74/lib/Cake/Cache/Engine/FileEngine.php, getStackTrace at line 369
    [1] => /php74/lib/Cake/Cache/Engine/FileEngine.php, _setKey at line 116
    [2] => /php74/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php, write at line 317
    [3] => /php74/app/Plugin/DebugKit/Controller/Component/ToolbarComponent.php, write at line 503
    [4] => /php74/app/Plugin/DebugKit/Controller/Component/ToolbarComponent.php, _saveState at line 333
    [5] => /php74/lib/Cake/Utility/ObjectCollection.php, beforeRender at line 129
    [6] => /php74/lib/Cake/Event/CakeEventManager.php, trigger at line 244
    [7] => /php74/lib/Cake/Controller/Controller.php, dispatch at line 949
    [8] => /php74/lib/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php, render at line 200
    [9] => /php74/lib/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php, _invoke at line 167
    [10] => /php74/app/webroot/index.php, dispatch at line 108
)

/php74/app/tmp/cache/cake_toolbar_cache0492a2202935e74850f2aed479dc3a99

Fatal error: [snuffleupagus][disabled_function] Aborted execution on call of the function 'chmod', because its argument '$mode' content (436) matched a rule in /php74/lib/Cake/Cache/Engine/FileEngine.php on line 372


Array
(
    [0] => /php74/lib/Cake/View/View.php, getStackTrace at line 972
    [1] => /php74/lib/Cake/View/View.php, _evaluate at line 933
    [2] => /php74/lib/Cake/View/View.php, _render at line 546
    [3] => /php74/lib/Cake/View/View.php, renderLayout at line 481
    [4] => /php74/lib/Cake/Controller/Controller.php, render at line 976
    [5] => /php74/lib/Cake/Error/ExceptionRenderer.php, render at line 292
    [6] => /php74/lib/Cake/Error/ExceptionRenderer.php, _outputMessage at line 213
    [7] => /php74/lib/Cake/Error/ExceptionRenderer.php, _cakeError at line 190
    [8] => /php74/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php, render at line 127
    [9] => /php74/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php, handleException at line 269
    [10] => /php74/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php, handleFatalError at line 212
    [11] => /php74/lib/Cake/Core/App.php, handleError at line 986
    [12] => /php74/lib/Cake/Core/App.php, _checkFatalError at line 959
    [13] => ?, shutdown at line ?
)


/php74/app/View/Layouts/default.ctp


Fatal error: [snuffleupagus][disabled_function] Aborted execution on call of the function 'include' in /php74/lib/Cake/View/View.php on line 974
```

Comment: Your installation of PHP7.4 appears to have some security settings blocking those functions from being used. This isn't a CakePHP issue, it's a PHP configuration thing.

Comment: @GregSchmidt, The `include` function worked but just for the file: `/php74/app/View/Layouts/default.ctp`

Comment: I expect that [this](https://snuffleupagus.readthedocs.io/) may be of some use to you.

Comment: Thanks @GregSchmidt, I asked the server admin to check the problem, and seems their config has some problems, because just with php7.4 I had problem. The problem resolved